# How do I...Connecting to a Microsoft JET 4.0 database (.mdb) over a LAN network

Tags: database, vb6, ole

I'm building a vb6 application and I need to run it on a LAN network on Windows XP or newer. So far, I've made an algorithm to make and manage databases (Microsoft JET 4.0 databases .mdb) and I can normally use them while on a network using this connection string:

Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\192.168.1.20\SharedFolder\Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

But I need to access a database from my application that's for example in a shared folder on another PC over LAN network. And I know that if I try to open a shared folder on Win7 "Computer\Network\DistantPC\SharedFolder" it pops up a window that says "Username" and "Password". So it has password protection which I need to resolve too.

Probably all I need is a good, unique connection string that can access a database like "\192.168.1.20\SharedFolder\Data.mdb" without throwing an exception about permission. I can access it like this, but only when I disable passworded sharing on that host PC.

Please help... Thanks !

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer the .mdb over an express version of SQL server? MySQL and Postgresql also run on windows and have relatively small foot prints.

Comment: In any case I don't see a programming question here.